# Python/Numpy: Is there an efficient way to calculate moving averages with multiple windows?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

Part of a program I'm writing has code that calculates the following:

```
data = np.array(..........)
param = np.array(range(100)+1)
result = np.array([data[-x:].mean() for x in param])
```

This code is used in a giant loop so performance is crucial. It shows that the 3rd line (result = ...) takes the most time of all - I wonder if there are better ways to do this operation?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: `np.array(range(100)+1)` this isn't valid?  Do you mean `np.arange(100)+1`?  Also, are you really collecting the averages of the array backwards  (last sample, last 2 samples, last 3 samples, etc.)

Comment: Removing `data-science` tag as it's not relevant here.

Comment: For the first part indeed was a typo, but yes I will be collecting backward averages.. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you add 0 to the beginning of the array, and then create its cumulative sum using `np.cumsum`, then finding the average between indices i and j and just
`(my_cumsum[j] - my_cumsum[i]) / (j - i)`.

This should let you vastly simplify your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```
data[::-1].cumsum()[:100]/np.arange(1,101)
```